# How to handle Multi-Threaded requests to mysql to get a free row?

Tags: mysql, multithreading

Suppose you have a table consist of 100k jobs which every one of them needs to be processed.

```
job_id (int)
job_details (whatever)
job_status (Enum: Not processed, Processing, Processed)
```

My core software which for example has 100 threads handles these jobs, so every thread needs a job to process, it gets a free job so it Queries a **Not Processed** job, mark it as **Processing** and after it has finished it will mark it as **Processed**

The problem is when 100 threads start to work since lots of threads start together when they query `Select * from jobs where job_status='Not processed' limit 1` `update jobs set job_status='processing' where job_id=%JOB_ID%` lots of them get the same job to process! Which is very wrong.

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `jobs` is an InnoDB table, then you can use a [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) in a transaction to assign a single job:

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_status = 'Not processed' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
UPDATE jobs SET job_status = 'Processing' WHERE job_id = ?
COMMIT
```

Specifying `FOR UPDATE` locks the selected row. Separate transactions (threads) that also execute the `SELECT` query will wait for the first transaction to complete.

Alternatively, if you modify the `jobs` table to record which thread has been assigned the task, then you could perform the assignment without a transaction. First of all, assign a single job, setting the job's `owner_thread` property to some identifier that is unique to the executing thread:

```
UPDATE jobs 
   SET job_status = 'Processing', owner_thread = ? 
 WHERE job_status = 'Not processed'
 LIMIT 1
```

Then retrieve the details of the job that has been assigned, using the executing thread's unique identifier:

```
SELECT job_id, job_details FROM jobs WHERE owner_thread = ?
```

Comment: In my experience MyIsam is lot faster than InoDB, is there a solution for MyIsam? Thanks

Comment: @EBAG The second solution I outlined (with the `owner_thread` column) should work with MyISAM tables.